# How to only allow the keyboard to appear upon pressing edittext field?

Tags: java, android, xml

Currently I have made it so that the keyboard only appears when the edittext field is clicked. How do I make it so that when I press the add button or the enter button (the 2 ways i have made it possible to add edittext input into the listview below)that the keyboard hides again, only reappearing when I click the edittext field again?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**only allow the keyboard to appear upon pressing edittext field**

If you want to hide keyboard for other events after inputting text , you can remove focus from the edittext by invoking `clearFocus();`

To show  keyboard on Button click, use

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

To hide keyboard on Button click, use it in your `onClick` method

```
edittext.clearFocus();
```

Comment: where would i add this: https://gyazo.com/687f51687771387d7e8e0e9210df873f

Answer (score 1):

> > This code will focus on editText and show keyboard when clicking on
> >     the button

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            });
```

> // This code will hide the keyboard, if it is already show

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });


public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity theActivity) {
        final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) theActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputMethodManager.isActive()) {
            if (theActivity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(theActivity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: when button is clicked i want it to hide tho

Comment: where do i add this tho? https://gyazo.com/687f51687771387d7e8e0e9210df873f

Comment: when you want to hide the keyboard, you need to call hideSoftKeyboard method, this will hide the keyboard if it is already shown.

Comment: (this worked for my button thanks so much) However how can i make the same thing work for when I click enter. https://gyazo.com/3962c4aef33205029f5e795ad23870af. @Jaspreet Kaur

Comment: plz read  this article, http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-enterkey-event-example.html

Answer (score 0):

To open the Keypad:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)
                                 getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(im null){
        im.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    }
```

To hide the kyepad:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(im != null){
        im.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
```

In your edit text add **inputType**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Is this the place I should add this. https://gyazo.com/301bdb4f604271e12f0f2baa112858b2. Wont compile now

Comment: From your image just above the return true. Place the code.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0534525aee6f82f4fdd2fb8569b7948f. Doesnt do anything. It compiles but the keyboard doesnt hide

Comment: Where you implement your MyKeyListener?

Comment: what about the latest image? @Vir Rajpurohit

Comment: @BorisCornelis I have updated my answer. Please check

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a04ad3e0aa5b88c0089664d551a3d89a. https://gyazo.com/a04ad3e0aa5b88c0089664d551a3d89a. Nope still not working

Comment: nope still there https://gyazo.com/5ca1995efb96027a827a229e21c13508 (i removed return true, but not return false (do i remove both)?

Comment: ? do you know what the problem might be